# Why is it advised to put a Styrofoam plate under an Erlenmeyer flask?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, heat

At school today, we were doing experiments with ammonium nitrate and sodium hydroxide, and mixing them with water into an Erlenmeyer flask (separate flasks, of course). My instructor told us that we had to keep a Styrofoam plate under the Erlenmeyer flask at all times.

After the experiment, she told us to find out why we put a Styrofoam plate under the flask by tomorrow or we would get a 0 on that assignment.

Does anyone know why? I'm thinking it's to protect the table from the heat or coldness of the flask, or to protect the table in case of spills. We have to get the question exactly as she wants it, so I am looking for help.

Comment: What observation did you make during/after the experiment? The zero sounds harsh but the question is a good one.

Comment: The first flask cooled to 17.5C and the second heated to 38.3C which to me wasn't very much

Comment: I really don't know what else, are my guesses correct?

Comment: So, as part of the experiment you measured the temperature difference for both?

Comment: Hypothetical situation: suppose your table was made out of a giant block of steel that was very cold (maybe cooled in a salt+ice slurry). What happens?

Comment: @chipbuster The temperature of the table would affect the reaction. Is that it?

Comment: @MaxW Yes I measured the temperature throughout the reactions

Comment: Think about the validity of your observations in the scenario @chipbuster proposes.

Comment: By the way: If you think you arrived at the answer you can post a self-answer here.

Comment: @bpedit what do you mean?

Comment: Would your temperature measurements be the same if you did your experiment as @chipbuster described? Wouldn't it be most meaningful if the temperatures you measured were only due to the reaction itself? Temperature changes during a reaction provide important information about the nature of that reaction.

Comment: @bpedit Unless you're heating the Erlenmeyer flask while it is in contact with the floor/desk, it would not act like a heat sink. Unless you're maintaining temperature for extended periods of time....Also, there's so little information that the OP gives...

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO Any temperature difference between the table top and flask provides opportunity for heat transfer. Styrofoam, being a poor conductor of heat, minimizes this. You can debate whether the amount of transfer would be significant, but that's beside the point of this being good science. It eliminates, at least minimizes, the table as a variable in the temperature measurement.

Comment: @bpedit The air (conductivity 0.024) will be at the same temperature as the table. The table is probably made of wood (conductivity 0.12 ~ 0.30) or epoxy (conductivity 0.35). Styrofoam, on the other hand, has a conductivity of 0.03. So on conductivity alone the table is around 4~10 times larger. However, there's surface area. Assume that the Erlenmeyer is a cone with radius $r$ and height $2r$. The bottom will be touching the table, but the rest of the cone is in contact with air. The outside of the cone excluding the bottom is around 2.5 times the surface area of the bottom.

Comment: Lets now include the inside of the flask. Assuming that the inside of the flask is a smaller cone of radius $0.6r$ and height $1.2r$ gives us a surface area that is around 1.8 times the bottom of the flask. So...around 4.3 times the surface area of the flask is in contact with a colder or hotter "surface". I mean sure, its a good idea..but I think it borders on tunnel vision. If the teacher is so interested in the effect of the table, why not use an oven or a cooler?

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO I don't understand the use of an oven or cooler. We're trying to minimize external influences not exercerbate them. I agree, as I've mentioned, the role of the table is minimal. The teacher here is making a point about the methods of science. Primary among those is the reduction or elimination of extraneous variables. I taught Chemistry for 24 years. While I might not have done anything as prissy as this teacher, I respect the point she is trying to make (although not the zero she threatens).

Comment: Our table is a phenolic resin countertop, if that gives more information.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46719/discussion-on-question-by-thunderbolt-why-put-a-styrofoam-plate-under-an-erlenme).

Comment: Spill of chemicals, not much on table but may sometimes contaminate some other places, and sometimes toxic/ corrosive chemicals do bad on us. How much cleanness is being expected, is depend upon the type of work done on this lab. For very-basic level pure chemistry I've never seen that much protection anywhere; however in a biology laboratory a mild contamination may spoil everything.

Answer (score 3):

You provided the additional information in the comments that your experiment was about measuring the change in temperature that occurs upon mixing. This should give you a hint as to whether the substances mix with water in an endo or exothermic manner.

When measuring temperature changes it is crucial not to influence the temperature of the reaction mixture in any way. Naturally, that would for example mean not to keep the flask in your hand (body temperature is typically more than room temperature). But some error sources are not as easily visible. In your case, the table top was an error source. Whatever the material, it likely conducts heat better than air — meaning that if your flask was on the table a significant portion of the heat generated (or used) would be conducted away (or onto site) by the table resulting in a lower change in temperature. That is why these experiments are typically performed under maximally insulating conditions. One of the best and widely available insulators is polystyrene because of its high air content (air is a good insulator). Hence, keeping polystyrene under a flask reduces the error caused by the table conducting heat.